# windows 8 can't see "Replace or Skip Files"

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualbox, taskbar, file-transfer

I have a Windows 8 machine, and I'm trying to copy a folder from `c:\` drive to a network mapped folder.

On the taskbar, I see that there's a “Replace or Skip Files” confirmation popup.

BUT I can't see the window anywhere.  I tried maximizing the window, but nothing happens.  I also tried minimizing all my windows to see if it's underneath another window, but I don't see it.  I tried clicking on it in the taskbar.  The only way I can copy the folder over is to delete the existing folder then copy.

Is there a way to fix this?  It seems like a bug.

Comment: Try repeated Alt-Tab keystrokes to toggle between running windows.

Comment: activate it on the taskbar and then try alt+space, a pop-up window should appear and then select move and move the window with the arrows on screen.

Comment: KYAAY, I tried ALT-TAB, but when it highlights the "Replace or Skip Files" window, I let go, and nothing happens.

Comment: Zina, I tried left clicking on it, then ALT-SPACE, doesn't work for me. I think it's because i'm in a VirtualBox guest, and the VirtualBox host is grabbing it.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: well, not sure where your replace window is, on the host or guest? and you might try to change the display resolution where the replace window is to a smaller resolution, it might appear.

Comment: I'm copying from Guest to the same Guest.  It's just that VirtualBox host always captures those ALT commands, so I don't see how to send it into the guest.  I just made the from/to windows very small, and I still don't see the confirmation popup.  It's there in the taskbar.  Also, I can see it when I hover my mouse over the taskbar (it shows a mini-view of the popup).

Comment: FYI, I've been playing around with this, and I have to say, it looks like that problem where the dialog box shows up UNDER the window that it's supposed to be on top of.  I'm sure we've all seen that before.  Normally, I just minimize the other window, and the dialog will appear.  But in this case, I can't find the dialog box even if I move the other windows around.  At first, I assumed that it had something to do with copying to a network location, but I still have the problem when copying from one desktop folder to another.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  The problem went away.  I think this was one of those mysterious "restart windows" problems.

I do not think any of my steps will reproduce the fix, but I will detail what I did anyways (just in case).

1. I ran Windows updates.  There weren't a lot, as this was a recent install.
2. Restarted twice.  (I already tried restarting a few days ago, but whatever I did today worked).
3. On the VirtualBox host, I reduced the number of CPUs from 4 to 2.
4. On VirtualBox Host, I increased the CPU execution cap from 80% to 100%.

Again, I do not think any of my steps above are the solution, but I think Windows must have self-corrected.